# What would cause "Cursor Operation Conflict" error in ADO with SQL Server on Windows 8 and Delphi XE3?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, tadodataset

I'm using Embarcadero Delphi XE3 on Windows 8 and I'm trying to connect with SQL Server 2000.

My program used to work correctly when I was using Delphi 2007 on Windows 7,
but now whenever I do transaction (Update, Insert, Delete) it gives me an error message saying `"Cursor Operation Conflict"` and continue working (commit the transaction).

I'm using `TADOConnection` to connect with the server
and I use `TADODataSet` to do transactions. I use `TADODataSet.Insert`/ `TADODataSet.Edit`/ `TADODataSet.Post`/ `TADODataSet.Delete` to do the transactions.

I couldn't post any piece from the code because it is general problem.

I would like to know what may cause this error to be able to debug my code and make sure that I'm not doing any wrong....

The error only appears when I use `clUseServer` in `TADODataSet.CursorLocation` property.

Comment: Have you try this hotfix? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324900

Comment: yes but still having this error

Answer (score 0):

i had the same error with some VB6 code, it even happened when i used a disconnected adodb.recordset

my solution was to create an entirely separate connection (to the same server) for my record set which seemed to resolve my issue

i don't know much about delphi but i thought it *could* possibly help